# Getting ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when calling AttachThreadInput in C++

Tags: c++

I get an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error code when calling `AttachThreadInput()`. Here's the block of code:

```
HWND hwnd = MYFINDWINDOW::FindWindowA(NULL,"GameWindowB");
if(hwnd==NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n","Error: Please start the game! Cannot find window error...exiting");
    exit(-1);
}

DWORD lasterror=GetLastError();
printf("Last Error code: %lu\n-------------\n",lasterror);
DWORD procid;
DWORD curthreadid=GetCurrentThreadId();
MYPROCESS::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&procid);
printf("GameWindowB process id: %d\n",procid);
printf("Current Thread's process id: %lu\n",curthreadid);
BOOL att=ATTACH::AttachThreadInput(curthreadid,procid,TRUE);
lasterror=GetLastError();
if(!att)
{
    printf("Error: Could not attach with game windowB ...exiting: %d\n",att);
    printf("Last error reported: %lu\n",lasterror);
    exit(-1);
}
```

And...here's the output of that block of code when executed:

```
Last Error code: 0
-------------
GameWindowB process id: 17100
Current thread's process id: 17644
Error: Could not attach with game windowB...exiting: 0
Last error reported: 87
```

I am using the following compiler version:

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01

Comment: What does `ATTACH::AttachThreadInput()` do? And what is in `procid` after the call to `MYPROCESS:GetWindowThreadProcessId()`? From the names, it's not clear which of the variables are thread or process IDs. `::AttachThreadInput()` requires two thread IDs, but it looks like a process ID gets passed.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: ATTACH::AttachThreadInput() is simply calling the function: `BOOL WINAPI AttachThreadInput(_In_ DWORD idAttach,_In_ DWORD idAttachTo,_In_ BOOL  fAttach)` I'm trying to attached 17644 (current thread id) to 17100 (gameprocess  id).

Comment: @KarstenKoop maybe I should be calling `GetCurrentProcessId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `GetLastError()` after `FindWindow()` *succeeds* is meaningless, the value is undefined.  Call `GetLastError()` only when a Win32 function *fails*, and *only* if that function is documented as reporting errors via `GetLastError()`.

But, in any case, you are getting `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` because you are passing a **process ID** to [`AttachThreadInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx) where a **thread ID** is expected:

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI AttachThreadInput(
>   _In_ DWORD idAttach,
>   _In_ DWORD idAttachTo,
>   _In_ BOOL  fAttach
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *idAttach [in]*
>
> **The identifier of the thread** to be attached to another thread. The thread to be attached cannot be a system thread.
>
> *idAttachTo [in]*
>
> **The identifier of the thread** to which idAttach will be attached. This thread cannot be a system thread.
>
> A thread cannot attach to itself. Therefore, idAttachTo cannot equal idAttach.
>
> *fAttach [in]*
>
> If this parameter is TRUE, the two threads are attached. If the parameter is FALSE, the threads are detached.

[`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) reports the **thread ID** in its return value, not its output parameter.

> ```
> DWORD WINAPI GetWindowThreadProcessId(
>   _In_      HWND    hWnd,
>  _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpdwProcessId
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *hWnd [in]*
>
> Type: HWND
>
> A handle to the window.
>
> *lpdwProcessId [out, optional]*
>
> Type: LPDWORD
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the **process identifier**. If this parameter is not NULL, GetWindowThreadProcessId copies the identifier of the process to the variable; otherwise, it does not.
>
> Return value
>
> Type: DWORD
>
> **The return value is the identifier of the thread** that created the window.

Try this instead:

```
HWND hwnd = MYFINDWINDOW::FindWindowA(NULL,"GameWindowB");
if (!hwnd)
{
    printf("%s\n","Error: Please start the game! Cannot find window error...exiting");
    exit(-1);
}

DWORD curthreadid = GetCurrentThreadId();
DWORD gamethreadid = MYPROCESS::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, NULL);

printf("GameWindowB thread id: %lu\n", gamethreadid);
printf("Current thread id: %lu\n", curthreadid);

if (!ATTACH::AttachThreadInput(curthreadid, gamethreadid, TRUE))
{
    DWORD lasterror = GetLastError();
    printf("Error: Could not attach with game windowB ...exiting\n");
    printf("Last error reported: %lu\n", lasterror);
    exit(-1);
}

...

// don't forget this when you are done....
ATTACH::AttachThreadInput(curthreadid, gamethreadid, FALSE);
```

Comment: thx! You are absolutely right and I'm a fool for not realizing my mistake. thanks again. I've accepted your answer.